# Как установить windows 10?

Tags: windows

Решил установить обновления винды, после перезапустился , комп начал проверку диска на ошибки , но думаю ладно пусть , хуже не будет, в итоге он завис на проверке, 2 часа без изменений, я перезапустил ПК, у меня после этого при запуске Виндоус просто черный экран, войти в безопасный режим не смог, мой Биос этого не позволяет, перепробовал все, так же пробовал вызвать окно с утилитой восстановления Виндоус, при запуске перезапускал специально ПК, но тоже безуспешно, в итоге хотел запустить утилиту восстановления через образ винды, сделал, включил комп, но тут при попытке установить Виндоус с флешки тупо фиолетовый экран, обычно на этом моменте так же должна появится кнопка установить но ее нет, что делать я не знаю

Образ делал через официальную утилиту

Comment: *Как установить windows 10?* Теперь, вероятно - подключить HDD к другой системе либо загрузиться с LiveCD, скопировать куда-то все нужные данные, потом проверить систему, особенно диск, на предмет проблем, и если всё в порядке, то снести ОС и установить начисто. Во всяком случае это самый простой выход имхо... *войти в безопасный режим не смог, мой Биос этого не позволяет* Загрузка в безопасном режиме не связана с BIOS.  *Образ делал через официальную утилиту* Если установка не стартует - либо проблемы с железом, либо криво сделалось.

Comment: А может быть такое что 2 раза утилита от Майкрософт плохо сделала образ ? Т.к у меня есть диск с 7 Виндоус, и он нормально запускается

Comment: *может быть такое что .. утилита от Майкрософт плохо сделала образ ?* Да запросто.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую у интернете образ лучше скачать, мне уже посоветовали один

Comment: У тебя десятка-то честная? если да, то надо не ломаные образы искать, а в личном кабинете Microsoft получить копию образа installation media.

Comment: Ну у меня она так же с официального сайта, но активации не было, постоянно надпись висела, если это можно считать честным то да, но я не покупал